# Callback animation to begin only after ALL children have finished animating

Tags: jquery

I have a div wherein I would like to fade all of the child elements out at once, but fade in a new element but only after all children have completed fading out.  Using my current code below, the #Message div starts fading in after the first child element and is actually placed after the last child.  Once the last child fades out completely, the #Message div then "jumps" up into position.  I want to avoid this "jump".

```
$('#DIV').children().fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $('#Message').fadeIn("slow");
});
```

How can I make certain the fadeIn() animation doesn't begin until fadeOut() is complete on ALL child elements of #DIV?

Edit:  I should note that my #Message div is located **inside** of #DIV.

Comment: According to the docs, what you have it right.  http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Comment: seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j8Pst/

Comment: The effect you want will work fine with the code you have, but if your animation time for fadeOut varies, you will need to make use of deferred objects (see post for details).  Note that the code in my post can also be used for any waiting mechanism (e.g. ajax calls)

Comment: I think you want deferreds. Read here: http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll want to use [deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) specifically for scenarios like this.  The easy part is that animations already create deferred objects by default: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/zTxrt/

```
$.when(
    $('#DIV').children().each(function(i,o) {
        $(o).fadeOut((i+1)*1000);
    })
)
.done(function() {
    $('#Message').fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Comment: actually, animations _do not_ automatically create promises.  The promise is created by calling the `.promise` function, and it happens that `$.when` does that for each passed parameter.  You could have written `$(...).each(...).promise().done(...)` instead of using `$.when`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#DIV').children().fadeOut("slow", function() {
    if($('#DIV').children().filter(':animated').length == 1) $('#Message').fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Basically count how many are still animating, and when there is only one left, run the callback.

This also makes your callback run just once, not once per element.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo. (I was missing the `.length`)

Comment: I still get the "jump" up as if #Message starts fading in before everything has finished fading out.  I should note that #Message div is located inside of #DIV; I've updated the original question to note this.